# Read large data from database using JdbcTemplate and expose via api?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

I have a requirement to read a large data set from a postgres database which needs to be accessible via a rest api endpoint. The client consuming the data will then need to transform the data into csv format(might need to support json and xml later on).

On the server side we are using Spring Boot v2.1.6.RELEASE and spring-jdbc v5.1.8.RELEASE.
I tried using paging and loop through all the pages and store the result into a list and return the list but resulted in `OutOfMemory` error as the data set does not fit into memory.

Streaming the large data set looks like a good way to handle memory limits.
Is there any way that I can just return a Stream of all the database entities and also have the rest api return the same to the client? How would the client deserialize this stream?

Are there any other alternatives other than this?

Comment: This is achievable with webflux and reactive database. Are you using webflux for reactive stream and what is your database?

Comment: The database is postgres and query the db using ```NamedParameterJdbcTemplate``` of spring-jdbc v5.1.8. I looked into r2dbc-postgresql for reactive database but it's not GA yet.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is so huge that it doesn't fit into memory - I'm thinking gigabytes or more -  then it's probably too big to reasonably provide as single HTTP response. You will hold the connection open for a very long time. If you have a problem mid-way through, the client will need to start all over at the beginning, potentially minutes ago.

A more user-friendly API would introduce pagination. Your caller could specify a page size and the index of the page to fetch as part of their request

For example

```
 /my-api/some-collection?size=100&page=50
```

This would represent fetching 100 items, starting from the 5000th (5000 - 5100)

Perhaps you could place some reasonable constraints on the page size based on what you are able to load into memory at one time.

Comment: I ended up using pagination to call the rest client and write data using ```StreamingResponseBody```. Thank you for suggesting this.

Comment: @mosranna sure, happy to help